# scanf() value ignored after reading a char

Tags: scanf

Got stuck on an problem getting more familiar with C(++) on Hackerrank. Using scanf() I want to read a line with a bunch of different values.

The issue is that the value after char is ignored. Read solutions to this was to add a space before the char, but I've tried running a scanf() on a seperate line per value, and only keeping the space infront of the char but still the problem persisted.

The lesson to be learned seems to be using scanf() and not any other type of input method. So no reading with cin or fscanf(). And reason for this being one can read all kinds of values on the same line. So I don't want to make more than this one line for reading the input either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i;
    long l;
    long long ll;
    char c;
    float f;
    double d;

    /** Read "3 444 12345678912345 a 334.23 14049.30493" from stdin */
    scanf("%i %ld %lld %c %f %lf", &i, &l, &ll, &c, &f, &d);

    printf("%d\n", i);      // 3, as expected
    printf("%ld\n", l);     // 444 also as expected
    printf("%lld\n", ll);   // 12345678912345 ...
    printf("%c\n", c);      // 'a' 
    printf("%f\n", d);      // 14049.30493 ?? It should be: 334.23
    printf("%lf\n", d);     // 14049.30493 but this time as it should be.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%i %ld %lld %c %f %lf", &i, &l, &ll, &c, &f, &d);
                                                 ^
                                                !F!  D

printf("%d\n", i);
printf("%ld\n", l);
printf("%lld\n", ll);
printf("%c\n", c);
printf("%f\n", d);      // < D!
printf("%lf\n", d);     // < D!
```

You are printing the `d` variable twice and never `f`.